# Adding Libraries--Nothing to Add

Tags: android, reference, dependencies

I simply wish to resolve the references but it does not work. 
I have the required JARs in the libs folder of my app (MainActivity/libs):

[image]

Yet as I try to simply to alleviate these missing requirements:
[image]

I click "Add", and this empty dialogue pops up, nothing to choose from even though the JARs are still there:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the jars with the required classes on the classpath already (according to your first image), so I don't think you even need those references with the red X's in the second image. You can remove them. That section is for referencing other Eclipse projects as dependencies, if I recall correctly.

Comment: This solved that particular problem, but the issue was that I had duplicate jars on Android dependencies and private libraries

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the project references from the Java Build Path ...
Then Clean the Project.
Then Close the Project.
Reopen the Opject.
After all the above process Trying adding references to libraries in build path